# my constructor is doing work. Is this a code smell in this example?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js

I have created a queue in javascript. This queue also has blocking `take()`. As you all probably know this is not really true, because javascript does not have threads. It just wait until element has been added to queue. You can view to source-code at https://gist.github.com/2467432. I try to [write testable code](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/08/by-miko-hevery-so-you-decided-to.html). As you can see from my code below [my constructor does real work](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/)?

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter,
    Queue = module.exports = function Queue() {
    /*  Constructor is doing work..?? 
    */
    var _emitter    = this._emitter     = new EventEmitter(),
        _awaiting   = this._awaiting    = [],
        _queue      = this._queue       = [];

    _emitter.on('offer', function (data) {
        _awaiting.shift()(data);
    });

};
```

My question is if this a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)? I think this class(object) is a [leaf of application graph(value-object)](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/08/by-miko-hevery-so-you-decided-to.html), so maybe it is not such a big deal. This way I think I can keep my [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface#API_in_object-oriented_languages) clean(easy to use). I think my class is still easy to test as you can hopefully see from my test class.

> Value-objects, these tend to
>   have lots of getters / setters and are very easy to construct are
>   never mocked, and probably don't need an interface. (Example:
>   LinkedList, Map, User, EmailAddress, Email, CreditCard, etc...). (2)
>   Service-objects which do the interesting work, their constructors ask
>   for lots of other objects for colaboration, are good candidates for
>   mocking, tend to have an interface and tend to have multiple
>   implementations (Example: MailServer, CreditCardProcessor,
>   UserAthenticator, AddressValidator).

If you think it is a code smell I would like to know how you would fix this(but still keep the tests pass  without any modification if possible?)

Comment: PS: Your code does not actually work (`Array.prototype.shift` does not return a function). Also, starting a property name with `_` does not make it private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally the only issue I see with the code in terms of your constructor doing real work or testability is the instantiation of an `EventEmitter` object. Doing this in the constructor prevents you from mocking out or injecting a different class/instance for testing. You could use [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) as a simply way to resolve this:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter,
    Queue = module.exports = function Queue( emitter ) {
    /*  Constructor is doing work..?? 
    */
    var _emitter    = this._emitter     = emitter,
        _awaiting   = this._awaiting    = [],
        _queue      = this._queue       = [];

    _emitter.on('offer', function (data) {
        _awaiting.shift()(data);
    });

};
```

Comment: I know about dependency injection. But I like to keep my API as simple as possible because I want to publish it as module for example. I think in that case a clean constructor would be best? I want to expose the class as in the test if possible.

Comment: In that case if you *really* care about it you could optionally pass in a emitter or just omit it altogether. Something like var _emitter    = this._emitter     = emitter || new EventEmitter(),